# Android OnTouch gives an error

Tags: java, android

First of all: We are new to Android Development and we have an exercise we do not understand what we need to do.

We need to add an OnTouchListener to a touchView, according to the course slides this can be done as described below but it is not working:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

TouchView touchView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    this.setContentView(ll);

    float x = 500;
    float y = 500;
    float size = 1000;

    touchView = new TouchView(x,y,size,this);
    touchView.setOnTouchListener(this);
    ll.addView(touchView);
}

public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent){
    float x = motionEvent.getX();
    float y = motionEvent.getY();

    return  true;
}
```

With the touchView class as shown below:

```
public class TouchView extends View {

public float x,y,size;
Paint paint = new Paint();

public TouchView(float xcor, float ycor, float sizenum, Context context) {

    super(context);
    x = xcor;
    y = ycor;
    size = sizenum;
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

}



@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, size, paint);
}

public TouchView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet){

    super(context, attributeSet);

}
}
```

Unfortunately, it is not working and we are at a total loss as to how we can make it work. Can someone help us out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implement OnTouchListener {

   TouchView touchView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        this.setContentView(ll);

        float x = 500;
        float y = 500;
        float size = 1000;

        touchView = new TouchView(x,y,size,this);
        touchView.setOnTouchListener(this);
        ll.addView(touchView);
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent){
        float x = motionEvent.getX();
        float y = motionEvent.getY();

        return  true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thankyou this did solve our current issues, for some reason this did not work when we tried it earlier. Luckily it does now, must me something to do with another edit that has been made.

Comment: Does anyone know why the onTouch would be triggered twice instead of once on a single click?

Comment: Because first it'll call for `ACTION_DOWN` when you press the view second it'll call  `ACTION_UP` taking off you're finger from the view

Comment: Oh wow, that was a gross oversight on our parth. Thanks an infinite amount to you!